Can a player cast an instant at anytime during an opponent's turn?
So I had the following situation in a very casual MtG match:

I've played Chandra, Flamecaller, a 4-loyalty planeswalker;
Then my opponent cast Boros Charm "in response to" that spell, targeting Chandra herself.

I argued that it was not possible, since at that moment Chandra was not a valid target (because the spell hasn't yet resolved). So far so good.
Then my opponent argued, "Well OK, then I'll cast Boros Charm right after she's summoned".
From what I've learned playing a bit of Arena, I explained that it is also not possible -- since I have priority on my turn, and I have not done any effect yet (or moved to the next turn phase) to warrant a response, I still could (for example) use her +1 loyalty ability even before Boros Charm could be cast. The ability would bring her to +5 loyalty and effectively survive 4 points of direct damage. I still would have the priority during my turn.
He argued however that an "instant can be played anytime", such that he could cast Boros Charm before I could use her +1 loyalty ability (and since it's a slow effect, that effect would not enter the stack, and she would not survive).
Who is right? More technically, is it the case that a player can initiate a new stack by using any instant-like ability or spell, which is not a mana ability, anytime outside his turn?

Keep in mind that if you do anything else that uses the stack, your opponent will be able to target Chandra with the Boros Charm, and you could lose the opportunity to use the loyalty ability - even if that action has nothing to do with Chandra. In situations where there are strategic reasons not to use the loyalty ability immediately, this risk must sometimes be weighed carefully.

@KarlKnechtel Yes, absolutely, that's pretty much clear for me right now.

Does this answer your question? Can I kill Lurrus directly after it enters the battlefield, before it's controller gets priority to cast a permanent from their graveyard? You want to cast Boros Charm before Chandra activates her ability. They want to kill Lurrus before Lurrus activates her ability.

@KarlKnechtel That's not true, but only because you said "anything". Most things, yes, would give your opponent an opportunity to respond with Boros Charm. But if you cast a spell with "Split Second", such as Angel's Grace, then your opponent will be unable to cast Boros Charm until your split second spell eventually resolves, at which point you'll have priority again.

@Rainbolt Ah, yes, that does use the stack, fair.

Does this answer your question? Destroying a Planewalker before its ability is used (Better duplicate than proposed above)

@ryanyuyu +Rainbolt Both do, though I think the way I framed my question is better for the purpose of clarifying priority rules. The planeswalker situation was merely an example where this rule affects materially the outcome.

You are right and your opponent was wrong. A player can only use abilities (including mana abilities1) or cast spells only when that player has priority. In your specific case, because the active player (AP, you) gets priority first every time a spell or ability resolves, there is (almost2) never a time where Chandra has resolved where the non-active player(s) (NAP, your opponent) can cast a spell or activate an ability before the AP can activate one of those abilities. Priority is covered in the Comprehensive Rules under section 117. The rules for what you can do when you have priority are covered by 117.1 (emphasis mine):

117.1 Unless a spell or ability is instructing a player to take an action, which player can take actions at any given time is determined by a system of priority. The player with priority may cast spells, activate abilities, and take special actions.

117.1a A player may cast an instant spell any time they have priority. A player may cast a noninstant spell during their main phase any time they have priority and the stack is empty.
117.1b A player may activate an activated ability any time they have priority.
117.1c A player may take some special actions any time they have priority. A player may take other special actions during their main phase any time they have priority and the stack is empty. See rule 116, “Special Actions.”
117.1d A player may activate a mana ability whenever they have priority, whenever they are casting a spell or activating an ability that requires a mana payment, or whenever a rule or effect asks for a mana payment (even in the middle of casting or resolving a spell or activating or resolving an ability).


And 117.3 covers when players will have priority (emphasis mine):

117.3 Which player has priority is determined by the following rules:

117.3a The active player receives priority at the beginning of most steps and phases, after any turn-based actions (such as drawing a card during the draw step; see rule 703) have been dealt with and abilities that trigger at the beginning of that phase or step have been put on the stack. No player receives priority during the untap step. Players usually don’t get priority during the cleanup step (see rule 514.3).
117.3b The active player receives priority after a spell or ability (other than a mana ability) resolves.
117.3c If a player has priority when they cast a spell, activate an ability, or take a special action, that player receives priority afterward.
117.3d If a player has priority and chooses not to take any actions, that player passes. If any mana is in that player’s mana pool, they announce what mana is there. Then the next player in turn order receives priority.




See 117.1d - while many people think mana abilities can be activated any time, they do have restrictions, these restrictions are just looser than they are for casting spells and activating non-mana abilities.
Because activating a planeswalker ability is sorcery speed, if the planeswalker entering the battlefield causes an ability to trigger, that trigger will go on the stack before AP can use the planeswalker's ability.


Thanks for your detailed answer; in particular the footnote 2 is very interesting in that it could backfire against me if I had such effect available.

@alecov At the moment, there aren't that many Planeswalkers with built-in ETB effects (I found [mtg: Jace, Mirror Mage], [mtg: Minsc & Boo, Timeless Heroes], [mtg: Niko Aris], and [mtg: Teyo, Geometric Tactician]). Other cards that trigger when a planewalker ETBs are not common either, and they typically care only about your planeswalkers ([mtg: Cloudstone Curio], [mtg: Yoshimaru, Ever Faithful], [mtg: Kodama of the East Tree], for example). So if you are playing any of these cards, this rule is especially important.

@bradC mostly, but there are multi-card ways to set up these triggers too, for example Mycosynth Lattice or Enchanted Evening already in play making all permanents artifacts or enchantments respectively would open up a lot more triggers off of planeswalker ETBs

@BradC Yeah, the important thing here is that the rulings apply to any similar situation, and there are many ETBs for other permanents in general :)

And of course the [basic rules] don't do such a good job at explaining this, the text says "After a spell or ability resolves, both players again get the chance to respond." but it's not really explicit about the active player getting to go first. A bit before that it says "When you have finished putting spells and abilities on the stack, priority then passes to the next player in turn order", hinting at it, but still not being too clear about it, sigh.

google found me a 2013 PDF rulebook which does have the details too, even if only in the small print in the glossary (p. 30)

Should that very last part in the answer say that the trigger goes on stack and resolves before the planeswalker's ability can be used? (Wouldn't the trigger go on the stack first even if the ability could be used at instant speed?)

One think I think trips a lot of people up is thinking about “fast effects” vs “slow effects”. This is a really bad way of thinking. Instants are not faster than sorceries or creatures. They simply have more allowed windows of time when they can be used.

@alecov The design team tends to avoid making planeswalker ETB triggers precisely because of the potential for them to backfire. For example, I remember reading that Interplanar Beacon's life gain ability was originally written to trigger on a planeswalker entering the battlefield, but they changed it to trigger on cast for the release version because playtesting found that the ETB version backfired way too much.

I'm not sure if it's worth mentioning, but one other corner case is a planeswalker getting played on your opponent's turn (like The Wandering Emperor), in which case the opponent would get priority first. Though in that case you could still respond to your opponent's Boros Charm or whatever by activating one of the planeswalker's abilities.

@ilkkachu it could be worded that way, but its more there focused on the movement of priority, not resolution of the ability

BTW, this only works because adjusting a planeswalker's loyalty is actually a cost of activating their loyalty ability, even it it's increasing its loyalty. If increasing the PW loyalty were part of the effect, then the opponent could cast a spell dealing damage to the PW, and the spell would resolve before the ability does.

@GendoIkari "One think I think trips a lot of people up is thinking about “fast effects” vs “slow effects”. " The terminology "instant speed" and "sorcery speed" can be somewhat misleading, but the concepts themselves are useful; activating abilities and instants have one set of timing rules, while sorceries and permanent spells have another.

@GendoIkari I think that confusion is mostly an issue for players who come over from yu-gi-oh where there is a spell speed system (particularly since they even use those specific words)

@Andrew Or to very old (albeit casual) Beta-era players like myself who actually never really learned the rules correctly :)

Which brings me to wonder whether this degree of precision in the rules was always there, or just came up relatively recently. I remember having read those small 4th-edition booklets which came with the decks decades ago, several and several times. Never crossed my mind anything about this priority system. On the other hand, the old term "interrupt spell" could have been preserved to help players understand that sometimes you necessarily need to "interrupt" the resolution of an effect before you could cast a given spell.

@Acccumulation a more accurate term would be "instant timing" and "sorcery timing", but I don't think the usage would change

@Andrew Interestingly, the way Ignition Effects used to be playable in response to a Summon in the Main Phase is a pretty good analogy for the long-time Yu-Gi-Oh! player!
